# How to inform kNN model of class imbalance and provide it with class imbalance ratio?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, imbalanced-data

Before asking this question, I assure you I spent 2 days researching this topic on the Internet. As I failed to find a concrete answer, I am taking this question here.

I am new to data science, and I am working on my first class imbalance project. I am trying to build models that do well at predicting which customers are likely to not show up for their scheduled appointment. In my dataset, "1s" are people who did not show up, and "0s" are people who showed up.

My y_test contains 1831 instances of "0" and 455 instances of "1". My class of interest is 19.9% of total y_test count.

I scaled my data and using scaled dataset to evaluate performance of KNN. I learned that KNeighborsClassifier has argument "weights". Its default value will not help me with my heavy class imbalance. By using 'distance' option, it only slightly improves confusion matrix and F1 score, but becomes heavily overfit. I notice that there is another option called [callable]. I read about it on scikit-learn.org and did additional research, but struggle to understand how I can use it to inform my KNN of class imbalance and class imbalance ratio (for example, like I was able to do for Logistic Regression).

Given my beginner's ML knowledge, "weights" argument seems to be the only argument to give me a chance to inform KNN of the class imbalance I am dealing with. Do you know how I can effectively use this argument to make KNN more knowledgeable of class imbalance? Documentation is not very descriptive on it, and Internet library is not rich on adjusting KNN for class imbalance. Therefore, I am reaching out here to see if someone has experience adjusting KNN for class imbalance, and how to do that effectively.

Thank you for helping me learn!

Comment: Not KNN per say, but when you do cross-validation you can use [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) cross-validation to make sure your classes have similar proportions to the overall dataset in each fold.

Comment: Is it possible that you collect more data? YOur dataset is too tiny, Therefore, the model that you will create, regardless of its structure will not be useful, even from a learning perspective.

Comment: @user1877600 I wish! :) It is a public dataset and I am practicing my skills. Entire data contains 10,000 observations, and my test set is 25% of that